# libcurl HTTPS enabled but not usable

Tags: c++, curl, https, cmake, libcurl

For our project we build libcurl from scratch over cmake. The libcurl-configure-out.log tells me it enabled HTTPS (among others), heres the important part about that:

> -- Enabled features: SSL IPv6 unixsockets AsynchDNS Largefile alt-svc HSTS NTLM HTTPS-proxy
>
> -- Enabled protocols: DICT FILE FTP FTPS GOPHER GOPHERS HTTP HTTPS IMAP IMAPS LDAP MQTT POP3 POP3S RTSP SCP SFTP SMB SMBS SMTP SMTPS TELNET TFTP
>
> -- Enabled SSL backends: OpenSSL

But when I try to set a TLS version in our code, it says "CURLE_NOT_BUILT_IN"

```
const CURLcode state = curl_easy_setopt(this->m_curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
// state == 4 aka "CURLE_NOT_BUILT_IN"
```

I also tried to verify over the curl executable, which kinda gives me the same impression

> C:<snip>\build\ex_libcurl-prefix\src\ex_libcurl-build\src\Debug>curl.exe --version
>
> curl 7.80.0 (Windows) libcurl/7.80.0 libssh2/1.10.0
>
> Release-Date: 2021-12-10
>
> Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap ldap mqtt pop3 rtsp scp sftp smb smtp telnet tftp
>
> Features: AsynchDNS HSTS IPv6 Largefile NTLM UnixSockets alt-svc

Where did I go wrong?

Edit: Some more parts about SSL beeing enabled:

> -- Found OpenSSL: optimized;C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/lib/VC/libcrypto64MD.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/lib/VC/libcrypto64MDd.lib (found version "3.0.0")

> -- Looking for openssl/crypto.h
>
> -- Looking for openssl/crypto.h - found

> -- Looking for cldap_open in wldap32;winmm;ws2_32;OpenSSL::SSL;OpenSSL::Crypto
>
> -- Looking for cldap_open in wldap32;winmm;ws2_32;OpenSSL::SSL;OpenSSL::Crypto - found

Comment: Your curl executable is not reporting HTTPS (or any of the other secure protocols) is enabled.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but why does the cmake protocol say so?

Comment: At a guess open ssl isn't available so ssl doesn't get enabled

Comment: @Narase I think you meant to address that to Alan, not me

Comment: @S.M. our program and curl as executable didnt work at first, only after copying the DLL into the folder it run successfully

Comment: @AlanBirtles But SSL is also listed in the enabled features; I added some parts about where cmake tried to find SSL

Comment: Where have you got libcurl-configure-out.log from? curl cmake does not output such a file.

Comment: @S.M. it does when building something with ExternalProject_Add